# Same equation but different answers

Tags: math, computer-science, calculator

I am calculating a certain value X on a calculator, and the order in which I do the calculation yields different answers. Can someone enlighten me please, as to why this is the case ?

CASE 1:
X = (730 * 4800)/1024 = 3421

CASE 2:
X = 730 * (4800/1024) = 2920

- CASE 1 is actually closer to the desired result.
- There seems to be loss in accuracy in CASE 2 ... ?

Comment: Is this related to a specific programming language?

Comment: I encountered this while programming....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases an integer division was performed instead of a normal (floating point) division.

> Integer division is division in which the fractional part (remainder) is discarded.

In CASE 2, for example, an integer division was performed on (4800 / 1024) and the result was 4 (instead of 4.6875). From there on the multiplication resulted in 730 * 4 = 2920.

I am not sure which calculator you are using, but usually when you want to avoid an integer division you can use a floating number instead. In your case `1024.0`. Now if this is part of a specific programming language you might have to use a different notation, for example `1024.0f` or `(float)1024`.

To force a floating point division you need to change your calculations to

CASE 1:

```
X = (730 * 4800)/1024.0 = 3421.875
```

CASE 2:

```
X = 730 * (4800/1024.0) = 3421.875
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating division, some times we lose floating point precision. so when you calculate the division first, it gains some error. now when multiply the result after division, you actually multiplying the error. where you calculate the multiplication first, so we do not lose anything. Then it gets divided, so the error remains minimal.

try something like this `1/(1/10000)`. I am sure it would raise `ZeroDivision` error, but it is actually `10000` not `infinity`.